# python predefined function (__ symbol in python)

Tags: python, function, python-2.7

Hello there i am very new to python (and i am from java background ) my question is  does the predefined functions such as length, size or init (constructor of a class) starts with

```
__function__()
```

is this standard python syntax that every predefined should starts with  this symbol ? ( for example `touple.__len__()` )? if not then whats the purpose of use this symbol
i am asking this quesion because  this symbol confuse me a lot in python.

Comment: Take a look here, http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html

Comment: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions

Comment: This is documented in http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers and http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python, method names which start and end in a double underscore have special meaning and are, by convention, reserved (there is nothing preventing you from creating your own "special" names, but you should rather not). For example, they are used to implement operator overloading.

You can find a nice introduction in [A Guide to Python's Magic Methods](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html). You can also see the [Data model - Special method names](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) section of the language reference.

You should also note that methods with an initial double underscore and no final double underscore are treated specially by the interpreter (they are name-mangled so that you get a "private-ish" method). This has nothing to do with methods starting and ending with a double underscore.

Comment: They aren't reserved, but some such names have a special effect on the object they are of; they may modify the actions of operators on the object.

Comment: They are "reserved" by convention. You should not create names with a double leading and ending underscore. But, just like a lot of other aspects of Python, nothing in the language is enforcing it.

Comment: You should add that to the answer then.

Comment: I followed your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Something that begins and ends with a double underscore or often called a *dunder*, is a magic function or method. Usually, they make objects work with operators or base functions (like `len` or statements like `del`, so basically functions or statements of importance).

So, for example:

1. `__add__` is for the `+` operator
2. `__mul__` is for `*` operator.

So, if you have two objects of the same type say `Foo`, then `Foo('a') + Foo('b')`, would call `Foo('a').__add__(Foo('b'))`.

They behave as reserved words and have *some* protection. So, for example:

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 10

    def __len__(self):
        return "Cheese"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = Foo()
    print a.__len__()
```

would print out `Cheese` to the console. However, this would give you a `TypeError`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = Foo()
    print len(a)
```

Answer (score -2):

the __ and _ symbol is for "private" functions

usually you do not use function name with _*. functions that start with _* are usually python's and are being used so dont override them or something if you dont know what you are doing

if you want to make a function "private" you use _. e.g : def _myFunc()